# Replacing "to" and other prepositions

Tags: prepositions

One of the requirements of my English final includes removing all prepositions from a previously written essay. I'm having trouble getting rid of prepositions like "to", "in", "of", and other common preposition that seem like a requirement in writing. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources. I do not think you will find any guidance on removing prepositions, because the very idea that this might be a desirable exercise seems ridiculous to me.

Comment: How much are you allowed to rewrite? If you can rephrase "I gave the book to Sally" to "I gave Sally the book" or "The weather is nice in Portland" to "Portland's weather is nice" then that I'd just take that approach.

This is the sort of thing that would really be covered by a style guide.

Comment: The capricious removal of prepositions from a passage is the kind of tedious nonsense up with which I will not put.

Answer (score 1):

To is not a preposition when it precedes a verb. In that case, together with the verb, it forms an infinitive phrase.

> I need to go to the store.

In this sentence, the first "to" is not a preposition while the second one is a preposition. The first one is forming the infinitive "to go" while the second one is a prepositional phrase.

Here's how you could rewrite the sentence to remove prepositions:

> I need to go storeward.

Of course, your teacher might not approve of this because you have coined a new word by turning store into an adverb of direction.

A better strategy is to rethink the verb in question and come up with this:

> I need to visit the store.

Finally, if your teacher insists that "to" is always a preposition, you can pick an even better verb and do this:

> I should visit the store.

Honestly, it all boils down to understanding what you are really attempting to communicate and picking words that best accomplish that goal. It sounds to me like a rather enlightening exercise for you and I hope you put all the energy into it that it deserves.

Just remember this, if the goal is to remove prepositions, you will need to focus yourself on using more descriptive verbs, adverbs, and adjectives.

A thesaurus will be helpful.